# Quarkus: dockerfile.jvm vs dockerfile.native

Tags: java, spring, docker, devops, quarkus

can you explain to me what is the difference between a Dockerfile.jvm and Dockerfile.native image ?
I know that each one has its purpose based image, but I have not understood the utility of each and in what context I use them ?

Thank you :)

Comment: Could you link to where you found the `Dockerfile`s?

Comment: If you are referring to the dockerfile you can find in the [quarkus quickstart project on github](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus-quickstarts), what is unclear in 1) the extenstion names in themselves 2) the comments at top of each files being **native**: `This Dockerfile is used in order to build a container that runs the Quarkus application in native (no JVM) mode`, **jvm**: `This Dockerfile is used in order to build a container that runs the Quarkus application in JVM mode` ?

Comment: i follow this article and when i create my application i find two file under src\main\Docker folder https://quarkus.io/guides/getting-started#whats-next

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name is self explicit: you can build a Quarkus application either as a standard Java application or as a native executable using GraalVM (and `-Dnative`).

If you do the former, then use `Dockerfile.jvm`, if you do the latter, use `Dockerfile.native`.

Comment: this means that the image of docker.native will be generated in binary language (machine language) and the application for the image docker.jvm is in bytecode format that is why we add the jvm to the image ?

Comment: Yes exactly. The native executable doesn't require a JVM.